# Need to remove duplicates keeping highest date one and lowest env one

Tags: sql, oracle, duplicates

I have a table -SO_RPT_BASEOFFER_LVL1 as under

```
DEPLOYMENT_DATE, STATUS, FROM_ENV, SO_ID,   SO_NAME,    SO_DESCRIPTION,     OFFER_ID,   SO_CATEGORY,    SO_TYPE, DISPOSITION,   SECTION, MAIN_PERMUTATION,  SO_LOB,     PRIORITY,   ASSOCIATED_GROUP,   ADE_PRIORITIZED,    ADE_NAME

01-JAN-01   ID  0   CVOIP_BASE_PROMO_VS0011 VOIP Unlimited Secondary Line $7.50 flat rate ongoing   Non Management Discount 88341523    Telephone   BASE_PROMO  Y           CVOIP   40      Y   VS0011-Non Management Discount
01-JAN-01   ID  3   CVOIP_BASE_PROMO_VS0011 VOIP Unlimited Secondary Line $7.50 flat rate ongoing   Non Management Discount 88341523    Telephone   BASE_PROMO  Y           CVOIP   40      Y   VS0011-Non Management Discount
03-MAR-17   ID  2   CVOIP_BASE_PROMO_VS0011 VOIP Unlimited Secondary Line $7.50 flat rate ongoing   Non Management Discount 88341523    Telephone   BASE_PROMO  Y           CVOIP   20      Y   VS0011-Non Management Discount
04-FEB-17   ID  1   CVOIP_BASE_PROMO_VS0011 VOIP Unlimited Secondary Line $7.50 flat rate ongoing   Non Management Discount 88341523    Telephone   BASE_PROMO  Y           CVOIP   20      N   VS0011-Non Management Discount
01-JAN-01   P   0   CVOIP_BASE_PROMO_VS0029 Voice 200 Install NRC 100% off 0 mo VS0029  100% off Installation Fee   88427443    Telephone   BASE_PROMO  Y           CVOIP   20      Y   VS0029-100% off Installation Fee
01-JAN-01   P   1   CVOIP_BASE_PROMO_VS0029 Voice 200 Install NRC 100% off 0 mo VS0029  100% off Installation Fee   88427443    Telephone   BASE_PROMO  Y           CVOIP   20      Y   VS0029-100% off Installation Fee
01-JAN-01   P   2   CVOIP_BASE_PROMO_VS0029 Voice 200 Install NRC 100% off 0 mo VS0029  100% off Installation Fee   88427443    Telephone   BASE_PROMO  Y           CVOIP   20      Y   VS0029-100% off Installation Fee
01-JAN-01   P   3   CVOIP_BASE_PROMO_VS0029 Voice 200 Install NRC 100% off 0 mo VS0029  100% off Installation Fee   88427443    Telephone   BASE_PROMO  Y           CVOIP   20      Y   VS0029-100% off Installation Fee
01-JAN-01   P   0   HSIA_ADITIONAL_PROMO_IS0236 SAVE Promotional Offer  SAVE - $15 off IPBB for 12 mo (1.5 - 75M)   88464673    Telephone   ADD_PROMO   Y           HSIA    6145        Y   IS0236-STACKABLE - SAVE - $15 off IPBB for 12 mo (1.5 - 75M)
10-JAN-16   P   0   HSIA_ADITIONAL_PROMO_IS0236 SAVE Promotional Offer  SAVE - $15 off IPBB for 12 mo (1.5 - 75M)   88464673    Telephone   ADD_PROMO   Y           HSIA    6100        Y   IS0236-STACKABLE - SAVE - $15 off IPBB for 12 mo (1.5 - 75M)
12-JUL-16   P   0   HSIA_ADITIONAL_PROMO_IS0236 SAVE Promotional Offer  SAVE - $5 off/mo ongoing w/HSI Upg (3-18M)  88464673    Telephone   ADD_PROMO   Y           HSIA    6148        Y   IS0236-STACKABLE - SAVE - $15 off IPBB for 12 mo (1.5 - 75M)
12-FEB-17   ID  1   HSIA_ADITIONAL_PROMO_IS0236 SAVE Promotional Offer  SAVE - $15 off IPBB for 12 mo (1.5 - 75M)   88464673    Telephone   ADD_PROMO   Y           HSIA    6145        Y   IS0236-STACKABLE - SAVE - $15 off IPBB for 12 mo (1.5 - 75M)
12-FEB-17   ID  2   HSIA_ADITIONAL_PROMO_IS0236 SAVE Promotional Offer  SAVE - $15 off IPBB for 12 mo (1.5 - 75M)   88464673    Telephone   ADD_PROMO   Y           HSIA    6145        Y   IS0236-STACKABLE - SAVE - $15 off IPBB for 12 mo (1.5 - 75M)
12-FEB-17   ID  3   HSIA_ADITIONAL_PROMO_IS0236 SAVE Promotional Offer  SAVE - $15 off IPBB for 12 mo (1.5 - 75M)   88464673    Telephone   ADD_PROMO   Y           HSIA    6145        Y   IS0236-STACKABLE - SAVE - $15 off IPBB for 12 mo (1.5 - 75M)
01-JAN-01   P   0   DTSTB_DTV4KGenie_L  DTSTB_DTV4KGenie    4K Genie Mini   88834924    Television  RACK_RATE_RC    N       DTV4KGenie  HSIA    6145    DTVSTB_LEASED   Y   DTSTB_DTV4KGenie_L
01-JAN-01   ID  1   DTSTB_DTV4KGenie_L  DTSTB_DTV4KGenie    4K Genie Mini   88834924    Television  RACK_RATE_RC    N       DTV4KGenie  HSIA    6145    DTVSTB_LEASED   Y   DTSTB_DTV4KGenie_L
01-JAN-01   ID  2   DTSTB_DTV4KGenie_L  DTSTB_DTV4KGenie    4K Genie Mini   88834924    Television  RACK_RATE_RC    N       DTV4KGenie  HSIA    6145    DTVSTB_LEASED   Y   DTSTB_DTV4KGenie_L
25-FEB-17   ID  3   DTSTB_DTV4KGenie_L  DTSTB_DTV4KGenie    4K Genie Mini   88834924    Television  RACK_RATE_RC    N       DTV4KGenie  HSIA    6145    DTVSTB_LEASED   N   DTSTB_DTV4KGenie_L
12-FEB-17   P   0   HSIA_ADITIONAL_PROMO_IS0236 SAVE Promotional Offer  SAVE - $15 off IPBB for 12 mo (1.5 - 75M)   88464673    Telephone   ADD_PROMO   Y           HSIA    6145        Y   IS0236-STACKABLE - SAVE - $15 off IPBB for 12 mo (1.5 - 75M)
```

Now i need to remove all the duplicate rows (duplicate based on fields- SO_ID, SO_NAME, SO_DESCRIPTION, PRIORITY and ADE_PRIORITIZED) keeping the row with highest deployment date and if deployment date is same then keeping the row with lowest from_env value.

I tried this

```
create table SO_RPT_BASEOFFER_LVL1_nodups 
as
with dups as 
( select DEPLOYMENT_DATE, STATUS, FROM_ENV, SO_ID,  SO_NAME,    SO_DESCRIPTION,     OFFER_ID,   SO_CATEGORY,    SO_TYPE, DISPOSITION,   SECTION, MAIN_PERMUTATION,  SO_LOB,     PRIORITY,   ASSOCIATED_GROUP,   ADE_PRIORITIZED,    ADE_NAME,
        row_number() over ( partition by SO_NAME,SO_DESCRIPTION, PRIORITY, ADE_PRIORITIZED order by deployment_date desc, from_env asc ) rn 
  from SO_RPT_BASEOFFER_LVL1 
) 
select  DEPLOYMENT_DATE, STATUS, FROM_ENV, SO_ID,   SO_NAME,    SO_DESCRIPTION,     OFFER_ID,   SO_CATEGORY,    SO_TYPE, DISPOSITION,   SECTION, MAIN_PERMUTATION,  SO_LOB,     PRIORITY,   ASSOCIATED_GROUP,   ADE_PRIORITIZED,    ADE_NAME 
from dups 
where rn=1;
```

But here my result is not correct. Somehow  the row

```
01-JAN-01   P   0   HSIA_ADITIONAL_PROMO_IS0236 SAVE Promotional Offer  SAVE - $15 off IPBB for 12 mo (1.5 - 75M)   88464673    Telephone   ADD_PROMO   Y           HSIA    6145        Y   IS0236-STACKABLE - SAVE - $15 off IPBB for 12 mo (1.5 - 75M)
```

is not getting picked up.

can someone suggest?

Comment: Clearly the combination of the four columns in the `partition by` is not  unique and there is some other record that rises to be first in the `order by`.

Comment: In the text you said "by SO_ID, ..." but I don't see SO_ID in `partition by` - which is right? Then: I can't tell where one field ends and the next begins, some commas would help (and lining up the columns would REALLY help). Also, what is the data type of the first column - is it DATE or VARCHAR2? And: are you creating a new table, or do you just need to delete from the existing one?

Comment: @mathguy- I can either delete from existing table or create new one. Yes data type for first col (deployment date) is DATE.

Answer (score 0):

The very last row, with a date of 12-FEB-17, seems to have the same values in the `partition by` columns, and a later date - so that trumps all the 01-JAN-01 rows, doesn't it?

Comment: Yes Mathguy... so i added deployment_date is partition and its works good.

Comment: @Mishti - that makes no sense, you said you wanted "highest date". If you add `deployment_date` to `partition by` then you will get one row for every different date, even with all the other columns in `partition by` being equal! What's the point of doing that?

Comment: @mathguy- with highest date i meant that if 2 rows have same value for name, desc, prior, ade_prior then amongst the 2 rows the one with highest deploy date is needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
select SO_ID, SO_NAME, SO_DESCRIPTION, PRIORITY,ADE_PRIORITIZED,
    DEPLOYMENT_DATE,min(FROM_ENV) as FROM_ENV
from
(
    select 
    SO_ID, 
    SO_NAME, 
    SO_DESCRIPTION, 
    PRIORITY,
    ADE_PRIORITIZED,
    FROM_ENV,
    max(DEPLOYMENT_DATE) as DEPLOYMENT_DATE
    from
    SO_RPT_BASEOFFER_LVL1
    group by
    SO_ID, SO_NAME, SO_DESCRIPTION, PRIORITY,ADE_PRIORITIZED,FROM_ENV
)
group by
SO_ID, SO_NAME, SO_DESCRIPTION, PRIORITY,ADE_PRIORITIZED,DEPLOYMENT_DATE
```

I have split the problem into two parts. First I try to pick the highest or recent date. And then if there are two I pick the least FROM_ENV.